# Flatten an arbitrarily nested list with recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have a question about recursion.

```
def f6(lst):
result = []
if type(lst[0]) == list:
    return f6(lst[0])
else:
    result.append(lst[0])

    if lst[1]:
        return f6(lst[1])

    else:
        return result
```

I want to make one dimensional list from multidimensional list input.
For example, when I put `["baa",[4,True,[10, 5],[1,2,['moo']]],['chirp']]`
,I want to take `["baa",4,True,10, 5,1,2,'moo','chirp']`

But it gives me `index out of range` error at `if lst[1]:`

Can't I use `lst[1]` as True/False condition?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're not taking care of conditions where a list can have an arbitrary number of elements and nested lists in any order. You'll need to initialise a `results` list, and then run a loop across each element to and check if the element is an instance of list (this is cleaner than `type(x) == list`) and if it is, make a recursive call, and extend the `results` list. Otherwise, append that element to `results`.

```
def f6(lst):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            result.append(i)
        else:
            result.extend(f6(i))

    return result
```

Calling this with `f6(["baa",[4,True,[10, 5],[1,2,['moo']]],['chirp']])` produces:

```
['baa', 4, True, 10, 5, 1, 2, 'moo', 'chirp']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Understood what I did wrong.

Comment: @WonKim If this answer helped, do consider marking it accepted. It helps the community. Thanks :)